# window.scroll(0,0) not working on Angular 10

Tags: angular

I'm working on an Angular 10 project. I have a button in the footer component. I want to make the browser scroll to top page. I've searched how to do it on the internet and found that I can user a **window.scroll(0,0);** function. But There is nothing happens when I clicked on the button.

Below is my template code,

```
<footer>
  <div>
    <a class="footer_logo" (click)="scrollToTop()">
      <img src="./assets/images/logo.png"/>
    </a>
  </div>
</footer>
```

And here is my footer.component.ts

```
scrollToTop(){
  console.log("scroll to top !");
  window.scroll(0, 0);
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Use [ViewPortScroller](https://angular.io/api/common/ViewportScroller) service.Which provide scrollToPosition method, You can that to scroll to specific position.

**footer.component.ts**

```
constructor(private vps:ViewportScroller){
}

scrollToTop() {
    this.vps.scrollToPosition([0,0]);
}
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-windowscroll00-not-working-on-angular-10?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 2):

In Angular, you can try the following :

```
<div #target>Your target</div>
<div>
    <a class="footer_logo" (click)="scrollToTop(target)">
      <img src="./assets/images/logo.png"/>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Then, in your component, just pass the element to which you want to scroll

```
scrollToTop(el: HTMLElement) {
    el.scrollIntoView();
}
```

You can reuse this code and scroll anywhere you desire.

Cheers!!